# how to create an array for calculation in php?

Tags: php, arrays, cosine-similarity

First, I have **rating table** in my database like this

```
=====================================
| id | userid | item_id    | rating |
=====================================
| 1  |   1    |     B      |   5    |
| 2  |   1    |     C      |   4    |
| 3  |   2    |     A      |   4    |
| 4  |   2    |     C      |   3    |
| 5  |   3    |     A      |   2    |
| 5  |   3    |     B      |   2    |
| 6  |   3    |     C      |   2    |
=====================================
```

Then I want to create an array from the table, and calculate the array. For more details, this is my code

```
<?php
include './connect.php';
$userid = $_SESSION['ids'];

$sql1 = "SELECT item_id, rating FROM rating WHERE userid='$userid' ";
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

$itemI = array();
$itemJ = array();
$items = array();

while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    $items[$row1["item_id"]] = $row1["item_id"];
    $itemI[$row1["item_id"]] = $row1["rating"];
    $itemJ[$row1["item_id"]] = $row1["rating"];

    $ditemI = $itemI[$row1["item_id"]];
    $ditemJ = $itemJ[$row1["item_id"]];
    $nume = 0;
    $den1 = 0;
    $den2 = 0;
    $rs = 0;

$sqlr = "SELECT AVG(rating) AS avgRatingUser FROM rating WHERE userid='$userid' ";
            $resultr = $conn->query($sqlr);
            $duser  = array();
            while($rowr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultr)){
                $duser[$u]["avgRatingUser"] = $rowr["avgRatingUser"];
                $duserU = $duser[$u]["avgRatingUser"];
            }

    for($i = 0; $i<count($itemI); $i++){
        for($j = $i+1; $j<count($itemI); $j++){

            $nume += (($itemI[$i] - $duser[$u]) * ($itemJ[$j] - $duser[$u]));
            $den1 += (pow(($itemI[$i] - $duser[$u]), 2));
            $den2 += (pow(($itemJ[$j] - $duser[$u]), 2));           

        $squart = (sqrt($den1)) * (sqrt($den2));
        $rs += $nume/$squart;
    }
}
}

echo $nume. " ";
echo $den1. " ";
echo $den2. " ";
echo $squart. " ";
echo $rs. " ";
```

then my question is, why the result of the array calculation is not showing?

and where is the error of my code?

Comment: you have to learn the scope of variables in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and

Comment: try to print the value in each step and u get to know , where you went wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem revolve around the fact that you use wrong index for both read and write.

In the first loop after `SELECT`-ing data, you add the following code (which is fine):

```
$items[$row1["item_id"]] = $row1["item_id"];
$itemI[$row1["item_id"]] = $row1["rating"];
$itemJ[$row1["item_id"]] = $row1["rating"];
```

And in the next codes, you read it like this (which also fine):

```
$nume += (($itemI[$i] - $duser[$u]) * ($itemJ[$j] - $duser[$u]));
$den1 += (pow(($itemI[$i] - $duser[$u]), 2));
$den2 += (pow(($itemJ[$j] - $duser[$u]), 2));
```

The problem is, from your table information, it is known that `item_id` is `A, B, C, ...` and you read the array in the later codes by using integer index taken from `for` loop code. You need to decide what kind of index you want to use for your array.

Comment: thanks for your answer